# Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError Call to a member function get() on bool in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I want to make a search function of user name and shift pattern id. Search by user shift pattern id works well but not for search by name. For more information, the **name** is inside the **user table** while **shift pattern id** is inside the **user shift pattern table**.

**UserShiftPattern model:-**

```
    public function uspname(){
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
```

**UserShiftPatternController:-**

```
public function index(Request $req)
{
    $usershiftpattern = [];

    if($req->filled('searching')){
        $usershiftpattern = $this->fetch($req);
    }

    return view('admin.usershiftpattern', ['usps' => $usershiftpattern]);
}

public function fetch(Request $req)
{
    $fname = explode(",", str_replace(' ','',$req->inputName));
    $fshiftpatternid = explode(",", str_replace(' ','',$req->inputShiftPatternId));

    $usershiftpatternlist = UserShiftPattern::query();
    $userusp = UserShiftPattern::with('uspname')->get();

    if(isset($req->inputName)){
        $usershiftpatternlist = $userusp->whereIn('name',$fname);
    }
    
    if(isset($req->inputShiftPatternId)){
        $usershiftpatternlist = $usershiftpatternlist->whereIn('shift_pattern_id',$fshiftpatternid);
    }

    $usershiftpatternlist = $usershiftpatternlist->has('uspattern')->get();

    return $usershiftpatternlist;
}
```

**VIEW:-**

```
<tbody>
                @foreach($usps as $uspslists => $uspslist)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $uspslist->uspattern->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $uspslist->shift_pattern_id }}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
```

**Got an error:-**

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
> Call to a member function get() on bool

Please help thanks

Comment: the data did not appear but got this tab error --> maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Comment: Dont you think we need to make relationship insisde the usershiftpattern model? what do you think?

Comment: i already get my query log, then @JohnLobo? How to read and understand the query? hmm :/

Comment: `name` in (?) [ShaharuddinBinMohamad] select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = ? limit 1 [55763] --> means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thin you need to modify your query

```
    $fshiftpatternid = explode(",", str_replace(' ','',$req->inputShiftPatternId));
    
    $usershiftpatternlist = UserShiftPattern::query();
       
    
  if(isset($req->inputName)&&!empty($req->inputName)){
    $usershiftpatternlist = $usershiftpatternlist->whereHas('uspname',function($q)use($req){
     $q->where('name','like',  "%{$req->inputName}%");
    });
}
    
    if(isset($req->inputShiftPatternId)){
        $usershiftpatternlist = $usershiftpatternlist->whereIn('shift_pattern_id',$fshiftpatternid);
    }
    
    $usershiftpatternlist = $usershiftpatternlist->has('uspattern')->get();
    
    return $usershiftpatternlist;
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233118/discussion-between-daisy-and-john-lobo).